# __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'fig' and 'func'

Tags: python, class, jupyter

I am really new to python, and just started using classes.
I am building a moving ball in Python, but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7cff16ca52e8> in <module>
     33     matplotlib.pyplot.plot(pos,5,'bo', markersize=5)
     34 
---> 35 animator=matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()

TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'fig' and 'func'
```

This is my code:

```
%pylab inline

time = 0


class Ball:
    def __init__(self,xvelocity=1, yvelocity=1, inx=1,iny=5, posx=[],posy=[]):
        self.xvelocity=xvelocity
        self.yvelocity=yvelocity
        #giving velocity
        self.inx=inx
        self.iny=iny
        #defining starting position
        self.posx = [self.inx]
        self.posy = [self.iny]
        

ball=Ball()
x=[0, 10]
y=[0, 10]
pos=int(ball.xvelocity)*int(time)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x,y, 'ro', markersize=0.0001)
for time in range(15):

   
    posx=int(ball.xvelocity)*int(time)
    if pos!=10:
        pos=pos%10

    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(pos,5,'bo', markersize=5)
    
animator=matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is check the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) in these cases. There we see in the function signature this:

```
class matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None, save_count=None, *, cache_frame_data=True, **kwargs)[source]
```

What that indicates is that it takes two required arguments, `fig` and `func` in that order, and then a list of optional arguments. In your code you are passing no arguments:

```
animator=matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()
```

So that needs to be updated to include those arguments to work. The documentation above should give you a good idea of what sort of objects are valid. For instance, we see that `fig` should be an object of type [`Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure). In your code you've not yet declared such an object, so you'd have to construct one.